# Write dataframe to storage container

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-blob-storage

Please help in resolving the below issue. I need to upload a dataframe (i.e. region) as a csv file into storage container (I only have blob_sas_url)

[image]

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient 
blob_sas_url = "https://.........."
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_sas_url)

## Upload file
with open(region, "rb") as data:
    container_client.upload_blob(name=output_blob_name.csv, data=data)
```

Below error,

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-e92dcc841981> in <module>
      5 
      6 ## Upload file
----> 7 with open(region, "rb") as data:
      8     container_client.upload_blob(name=output_blob_name, data=data)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: I think `region` is a dataframe, So `open(region)` does not make sense.

Comment: yes, region is a dataframe, not sure to export 'region' as csv to storage. can you please help here?

Comment: Hi @spartanboy, If below answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code. I tested in my system that converts dataframe to csv stores file locally  then uploads the file to blob storage

SAS URL Format:

**`https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>?<sas-token>`**

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

data = {'Product': ['Desktop Computer','Tablet','Printer','Laptop'],
        'Price': [850,200,150,1300]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['product', 'price'])

df.to_csv (r'path where file saved example C:\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

print (df)

upload_file_path="File saved Path Ex: C:\\export_dataframe.csv"
sas_url="SAS URL"

client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)

with open(upload_file_path,'rb') as data:
    client.upload_blob(data)

print("**file uploaded**")
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**The File saved Locally**

[image]

**The file uploaded to Container**

[image]